# how to split in ruby-scraping-ERROR undefined method

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, split

I am scraping the website https://www.bananatic.com/de/forum/games/. I want to extract only the year of the dates.

```
        require 'nokogiri'
        require 'open-uri'
        require 'pp'
        unless File.readable?('data.html')
        url = 'https://www.bananatic.com/de/forum/games/'
        data = URI.open(url).read
        File.open('data.html', 'wb') { |f| f << data }
        end

        data = File.read('data.html')
        document = Nokogiri::HTML(data)
        links3 = document.css('.topics ul li div')
        re = links3.map do |lk3|
        name = lk3.css('.name').children.text.strip.split("\n")[2]
        end


        date = ' '
        size_dates = re.length
        (0..size_dates).each do |i|
        unless i.nil?
            date = re[i]
            print date
        end
        end
```

As a result of the execution I get dates in what appears to be a String with the following format:
***day .month.year, hour:minutes***
[image]
***But I only need the year*** I have made a split but I get an error.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that if you look at the output from this block

```
re = links3.map do |lk3|
  lk3.css('.name').children.text.strip.split("\n")[2]
end
```

You will see:

```
["              07.08.2016, 13:47", nil, nil, nil, nil, "              06.08.2016, 9:24", nil, nil, nil, nil,...]
```

So you could solve your immediate issue by just adding `.compact` to the `end` or switching `map` to `filter_map`.

That being said here is another way to solve your issue:

You can get just the year from that text on that page using the following:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://www.bananatic.com/de/forum/games/"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(url))

doc
  .xpath('//div[@class="name"]/text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]')
  .map {|node| node.to_s[/\d{4}/]}
#=> ["2016", "2016", "2022", "2022", "2022", "2021", "2022", "2017", "2022", "2021", "2019", "2016", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2020", "2021", "2017", "2021"]
```

The 2 parts are:

1. `//div[@class="name"]/text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]` - the XPath which finds all divs with the class "name" and then pulls the non zero length (trimmed of white space) text nodes.
2. `.map {|node| node.to_s[/\d{4}/]}` - map these into an array by slicing the String based on a regex for 4 contiguous digits.

If you would like the XPath to be as specific as your post you can use:

```
'//div[@class="topics"]/ul/li//div[@class="name"]/text()[string-length(normalize-space(.)) > 0]'
```

Comment: Hello again. If apart from the year I also want to get the number of the month, what change should I make? I changed the [/d{4}/]} to [/d{2}/]} but I get the day, and I don't want the day.

Comment: @CindyAdrianaBohrquezSantana it would be`/\d{2}.\.\d{4}/`. Example and also a food place to test regular expressions https://rubular.com/r/02Od8DOOVYIIOx

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEX to get only the year after having the list.

Of course, if what you showing is the pattern. Will work. Years would be the only one with 4 straight digits.

Example:
17.01.2023, 17:40
this `\b\d{4}\b` will result in **2023.**